# nextjs ssr router.refresh does not have feedback

Tags: next.js, next.js13

*I'm playing with nextjs 14 as building ToDo app.*

There is page `/todos`. This page is Server Component so I get all todos in and pass it bellow.

*During download the todos I have Loading.tsx fallback component that is shown.*

When edit a todo and press save, request is sent and response is received with only 1 todo(not all). After it I use `router.refresh()` but it is not async and doesn't have feedback so this leads to bad UX.

This is my code:

```
function EditToDoForm(){
   const onSubmit = () => {
        setDisableUi(true)
        // editNote is server action
        editNote(props.note.id, inputState.name, inputState.body).then(() => {
            setDisableUi(false)
            // -->1: UI is enabled, not any loading animation
            router.refresh()
            // -->2: After some time just todos change - BAD UX
        })
    }
    // other code...

}
```

**The problem** User doesn't have indication that he edited/editting the todo because `router.refresh()` doesn't have feedback and when waiting the server to send the new todo I   can't show loading animation.

The only possible solution I found is to reload the page. How do you handle this scenario?